# How can I fix npm run serve error in terminal

Tags: vue.js, npm, visual-studio-code, terminal

I purchased Vue Material Dashboard Pro (vue-material-dashboard-pro-v1.4.0) and in the terminal I type npm run serve but it shows errors. How can I fix that?

> vue-material-dashboard-pro@1.4.0 serve /Users/desceliayoshe/vue-material-dashboard-pro-v1.4.0

> vue-cli-service serve --open

sh: vue-cli-service: command not found

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! file sh

npm ERR! errno ENOENT

npm ERR! vue-material-dashboard-pro@1.4.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve --open`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-material-dashboard-pro@1.4.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/desceliayoshe/.npm/_logs/2020-08-08T15_19_14_656Z-debug.log

Comment: Have u installed the Vue CLI [`@vue/cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try running `npm install` first